# How to create a 2nd TAP adapter for OpenVPN client on Win7/10

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I want to create 2 separate tunnels on 2 separate subnets, so I have 2 separate .ovpn (client) files.

The 1st tunnel comes up, but the 2nd one fails because of a conflict over the same TAP-windows adapter.  Evidently the 2nd tunnel needs its own TAP-windows adapter.

How to create a 2nd TAP-windows adapter?  Apparently there used to be a utility packaged with the Windows OpenVPN installer - but there no longer is.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

+1, I actually had to dig for this because the `Add TAP Adapter` link that used to be in the OpenVPN folder isn't there. This is because now it's a separate install ([see this ticket](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/320)), and as such the utilities are located in the %PROGRAMFILES%\Tap-Windows folder, under that folder there is a bin folder, and you can run the `AddTap.bat` script to add a new adapter, with elevated permissions of course.

Comment: Worked for me on win 8.1 as well, with the latest of everything as of now.

Comment: And for the Win 10 as well, as of February 2016.

Comment: Working on the latest Win 10 Anniversary Creators Hipster Millennium Update Version Edition, as of March 2018.

Comment: On windows 10 in 2021 I just had to type `add a new TAP-Windows6 virtual network adapter` on start menu. The file is under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OpenVPN\Utilities`

Answer (score 6):

There is already a **driver for new installation** at:

```
C:\Users\Luis->dir "%PROGRAMFILES%\TAP-Windows\driver\"
 Volume in drive C is Windows7
 Volume Serial Number is: 54AF-1483

 Directory of C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\driver

28/07/2015  01:22    <DIR>          .
28/07/2015  01:22    <DIR>          ..
05/11/2014  15:16             7.523 OemVista.inf
05/11/2014  15:16             9.194 tap0901.cat
05/11/2014  15:16            27.136 tap0901.sys
               3 archivos         43.853 bytes
```

You can simply install a new TAP adapter **referring this path** with the New Hardware Wizard at Control Panel (just running `hdwwiz.exe` on Win Vista and above). Select *Manual Installation* --> *Network Adapter* .

Tested on Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 SP1.

Example of my Windows 7 SP1 computer with a physical NIC, **2 TAP adapters**, a PPTP and a virtual NIC created by VirtualBox:

[image: Multiple network adapters]

Comment: An adapter created in such way is not visible to `openvpn --show-adapters`. besides, there's no way to delete it

Comment: its not visible to openvpn, but you can at least uninstall it from device manager.

Comment: Well, @basin ... even when the `openvpn` command-line tool can not see it, it should be possible to use it for connecting to another network by referring it on your `.ovpn` config file, in the `dev-node [Name]` part (comments in this section of the file say "# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name from the Network Connections panel if you have more than one", and the Network Connections Panel must see/show this new adapter). As for today I don't have possibility to test it (I would swear it worked the moment I wrote this answer, but I am not sure). Could anyone please confirm?

Comment: I have checked another computer, @basin , and I can confirm I configured PeerVPN ( http://www.peervpn.net/ , works with the same TAP adapter) using this manually installed driver. I have both OpenVPN and PeerVPN adapters that can connect to different networks correctly. I have edited my answer to reflect.